# Find fulltext indexes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, full-text-search

How do I find a list of tables that have a FULLTEXT INDEX applied to them on a given database?

For example, you can enable and disable a FULLTEXT INDEX like this:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[OBJECT_FACT] ENABLE

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[OBJECT_FACT] DISABLE
```

Comment: While it's deprecated and will cease to exist in some future version of SQL Server, through SQL Server 2012 you can still use the [system stored procedure `sp_help_fulltext_tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186929.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find a list of tables that have a `FULLTEXT INDEX`:

```
SELECT
    SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
    t.name AS TableName, 
    c.name AS FTCatalogName ,
    f.name AS FileGroupName,
    i.name AS UniqueIdxName,
    cl.name AS ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.fulltext_indexes fi 
ON 
    t.[object_id] = fi.[object_id] 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.fulltext_index_columns ic
ON 
    ic.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN
    sys.columns cl
ON 
    ic.column_id = cl.column_id
    AND ic.[object_id] = cl.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.fulltext_catalogs c 
ON 
    fi.fulltext_catalog_id = c.fulltext_catalog_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.filegroups f
ON
    fi.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i
ON 
    fi.unique_index_id = i.index_id
    AND fi.[object_id] = i.[object_id];
```

To enable and disable a `FULLTEXT INDEX` refer [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187960.aspx)

```
sp_fulltext_table 
   [ @tabname= ] 'qualified_table_name'         
   , [ @action= ] 'action' 
   [ 
   , [ @ftcat= ] 'fulltext_catalog_name'         
   , [ @keyname= ] 'unique_index_name' 
   ]
```

The preferred method is to use `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX [myFTindex] {ENABLE/DISABLE}` instead of the deprecated `sp_fulltext_table`.

Answer (score 2):

Paul's answer is great and helped me a lot but I was wondering why some of mine weren't showing up, the reason is that some of my FT indexes were on indexed views rather than tables.

A slight amendment to incorporate indexed views as well as tables would be:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
       o.name AS ObjectName,
       c.name AS FTCatalogName,
       f.name AS FileGroupName,
       i.name AS UniqueIdxName,
       cl.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.objects o
    INNER JOIN sys.fulltext_indexes fi
        ON o.[object_id] = fi.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.fulltext_index_columns ic
        ON ic.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns cl
        ON ic.column_id = cl.column_id
           AND ic.[object_id] = cl.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.fulltext_catalogs c
        ON fi.fulltext_catalog_id = c.fulltext_catalog_id
    INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
        ON fi.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
        ON fi.unique_index_id = i.index_id
           AND fi.[object_id] = i.[object_id];
```